# Azure Plan Test - Test Plan Settings - Release pipelines don't appear in drop-down

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I can't run a plan test with automation tests associated, because the release pipeline dropdown doesn't show the available releases pipelines.

I have a test associated with my automation test.
[image]
[image]
When I tried to run the plan test
[image]
[image]
Then I tried to set up my release pipeline
[image]
The dropdown doesn't show my current available release pipelines
[image]

Comment: Is your release pipeline defined with an artifact from the build pipeline you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Matt I had to add the artifact (from the Build pipeline) to my Release Pipeline

[image]